# Pivot table data in tabular format, first column should be column name and rest should be value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, unpivot

I just want to compare products that's why I need to show products with there attributes in column format. The First column will show attributes and rest of column shows attributes value for each column.

Simple select statement is as follows

```
SELECT  product_Id,product_Name,product_Price ,product_Description,product_weight  
from tblProduct
WHERE  product_Id in (1139,1140,1144)
```

Now I want to show my output in following way

[image]

I know that I need to use pivot to get that desired output. and i have tried in following way

```
SELECT MAX(ISNULL([1139],'')),MAX(ISNULL([1140],'')),MAX(ISNULL([1144],'')) 
FROM
(
  SELECT product_Id,product_Name,product_Price,product_Description,product_weight 
  FROM tblProduct where product_Id in (1139,1140,1144)
)s 
PIVOT
(
  MAX(product_Name)
  FOR product_Id in ([1139],[1140],[1144])
) AS PVT
```

but this only done for a single column but i needed for all attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are attempting to aggregate for attributes that exist in multiple columns, that is an indicator that you will need to apply both the [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) functions.

The UNPIVOT will take your column values and convert them to rows.  The code to unpivot will be similar to this:

```
select product_id, header, value
from
(
  select product_id, 
    product_name, 
    cast(product_price as varchar(10)) product_price, 
    product_weight
  from tblProduct
) p
unpivot
(
  value
  for header in (product_name, product_price, product_weight)
) unp
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/defb7/1). You will notice that there is a subquery in this that converts the `product_price` column to a varchar.  This is because the datatypes of the columns you want in rows must be the same. So you might have to perform data conversions to get this to work properly.

The unpivot generates a result that looks like this:

```
| PRODUCT_ID |         HEADER | VALUE |
---------------------------------------
|        141 |   product_name |  A141 |
|        141 |  product_price |   200 |
|        141 | product_weight | 200gm |
```

Once the data is in the rows, you can apply the PIVOT function to the `product_id` column values.

```
select header, [141], [142], [143], [144]
from
(
  select product_id, header, value
  from
  (
    select product_id, 
      product_name, 
      cast(product_price as varchar(10)) product_price, 
      product_weight
    from tblProduct
  ) p
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for header in (product_name, product_price, product_weight)
  ) unp
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for product_id in ([141], [142], [143], [144])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfb6f/3). This gives a result:

```
|         HEADER |   141 |   142 |   143 |   144 |
--------------------------------------------------
|   product_name |  A141 |  A142 |  A143 |  A144 |
|  product_price |   200 |   300 |  4000 |  5000 |
| product_weight | 200gm | 300gm | 400gm | 100gm |
```

The above version will work great if you have a known number of `product_id` values that you want as columns. But if you have an unknown number, then you will want to implement dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(product_id) 
                    from tblProduct
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT header, ' + @cols + ' 
              from 
             (
                select product_id, header, value
                from
                (
                  select product_id, 
                    product_name, 
                    cast(product_price as varchar(10)) product_price, 
                    product_weight
                  from tblProduct
                ) p
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for header in (product_name, product_price, product_weight)
                ) unp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for product_id in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/defb7/2). This will generate the same result as the static/hard-coded version of the query.

Comment: @rahularyansharma Thanks, I added a dynamic version of the code in the event you will have an unknown number of product_ids to convert to columns.

Comment: you make me your fan for pivot questions :)

Comment: actually i am already passing productIds as comma separated in stored procedure   @ProductIds nvarchar(500)

Comment: The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.

Comment: I don't want to run this query for all columns instead of that only productsIds i have passed in @ProductIds variable ... that can be maximum 4 only

Comment: @rahularyansharma If you have a max of 4 elements, then either one of these solutions will work. :)

Comment: now i am facing issue with column name of those 4 columns as they are changes everytime as first column name is header  i want to continue with rest of column names like Product1, Product2, Product3 and Product4 .. max to max there can be 4 products but minimum there can be  zero products.. but its OK for me if they return  null for columns which don't have values

Comment: @rahularyansharma I am not sure I understand.  Can you post a new question?

Comment: @rahularyansharma perfect, post the link here in the comments and I will take a look